# Decrypting a string into a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

Last week, I was assigned to encrypt numeric PINs into pronounceable strings (made up of vowel-consonant pairs). This went well.

This week, I've been assigned to *decrypt* the strings my function produced back into their original PIN form. I'm trying to reverse-engineer my code, but I don't know where to start.

Global variables:

```
CONSONANTS = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyz" 
VOWELS = "aeiou"
```

Encryption code:

```
def alphapinEncode(pin):
    '''(num) -> string
    Takes user input (pin) and converts it into a pronounceable string.
    Returns the string (codedPin)

    Examples:
    >>> alphainEncode(4327)
    'lohi'
    >>> alphainEncode(3463470)
    'bomejusa'
    '''

    codedPin = ""

    while pin > 0:
        last_two_digits = pin % 100
        codedPin = VOWELS[last_two_digits % 5] + codedPin
        codedPin = CONSONANTS[last_two_digits // 5] + codedPin
        pin = pin // 100

    return codedPin
```

Decryption code:

```
def alphapinDecode(codedPin):
    '''(string) -> num
    DOCSTRING PLACEHOLDER
    '''

    #This while loop checks validity of input string (string).
    testPin = codedPin
    while len(testPin) > 0:
        if testPin[-1] in VOWELS and testPin[-2] in CONSONANTS:
            testPin = testPin[:-2]
        else:
            print ("Your string is incorrectly formatted. Please use consonant-vowel pairs.")
            return None

    #Decryption code goes here!

    return #pin
```

Comment: "a bit of trouble" is useless information. **HOW** is this code not working?

Comment: What is the exception or unexpected output you are getting?

Comment: There is no code to run yet. The decryption code in alphapinDecode(codedPin) is not yet written, as I need help reversing the encryption done in alphapinEncode(pin). I need help taking the first steps, thanks!

Comment: *"I need help taking the first steps"* - then you're in the wrong place, SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but I see many other posts simply asking for code without presenting work. How should I go about asking my question?

Comment: And hopefully they're all getting downvoted too. Take the [tour], see [ask].

Comment: i don't think it's possible to reverse a modulo....i stand to be corrected though take a look at this `1 % 100`,  `101 % 100` and `201 % 100` equal 1

Comment: Didn't you write the encryption portion? I'd just take the general approach of reversing what you did there.

Comment: I also don't believe you can reverse a modulo but you know that all your numbers are between 0-100 so you can loop over them and plug them back into your encode and if it matches the last two digits of your encoded string then add it to your decoded string and remove the last two from the encoded string

Comment: @SirParselot this is just a division with remainder so it's quite easy to reverse, as `x == (x // y) * y + (x % y)` (in this case with y=5)

Comment: @mata Ah thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem with your spec: What happens when the string to be decoded is not even in length?

Ignoring that case, your approach should resemble this:

1. Split the `codedPin` into groups of 2, or take 2 characters at a time from the input. Keep these values so we can decode the current group of 2.
2. Reverse the algorithm you used to cypher the pins. Many comments are saying you cannot reverse a modulo operation - which may be true in the generic case, but since we are only dealing with positive integers, we can certainly reverse the value. Here's a hint: find the `index` of each character in the original `CONSONANTS` and `VOWELS` string to give yourself a number to start from. If you get stuck with the math, try manually decoding one of the examples on a piece of paper by hand. Pay close attention to the relationship between the index of the characters and the original PIN number.
3. Store the values for each pair of numbers until the end of the string has been reached.
4. Return or output the complete value.

I will not code the answer for you because I believe it would be best for you to come up with something on your own. Take these steps as a pointer and start to code! See what you come up with and come back, and you will have some code that you can use to ask an actual question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am reading through it now. To clear up the spec issue, the encryption function will only return strings that are even in length (vowel-consonant pairs), and the decryption function is supposed to work with those strings specifically.

Comment: When I take 2 characters at a time, should they be those at the front or back? Should I then subtract them from codedPin as part of a loop?

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting problem. I think this works:

```
pin = 123456789
c = alphapinEncode(pin)
c
'begomariwu'

sum([n*100**(len(c)/2-i-1) for i,n in enumerate([CONSONANTS.index(p[0])*5 + VOWELS.index(p[1]) for p in [c[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(c), 2)]])])
123456789
```

Or, with thanks to @mata for suggesting reduce, this improved one-line version:

```
reduce(lambda a,b:100*a + b, [CONSONANTS.index(consonant)*5 + VOWELS.index(vowel) for consonant, vowel in [c[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(c), 2)]], 0)
```

Now to get serious. One-liners can make for interesting puzzles, but real code should be readable. Here's my real answer:

```
def alphapinDecode(codedPin):
    pin = 0
    pairs = [codedPin[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(codedPin), 2)]

    for consonant, vowel in pairs:
        pin = pin*100 + CONSONANTS.index(consonant)*5 + VOWELS.index(vowel)

    return pin
```

I think this is reasonably clear without comments. As always, good variable names help a lot.

Your implementation of alphapinEncode is good, but still I rewrote it mostly with style changes, but also to use divmod:

```
def alphapinEncode(pin):
    codedPin = ''

    while 0 < pin:
        pin, current_digits = divmod(pin, 100)
        codedPin = (
            CONSONANTS[current_digits // 5] +
            VOWELS[current_digits % 5] +
            codedPin
        )

    return codedPin
```

Comment: Thanks! What does n refer to?

Comment: nice :) I had something similar: `functools.reduce(lambda a, b: 100 * a + b, (VOWELS.index(codedPin[i+1]) + 5 * CONSONANTS.index(codedPin[i]) for i in range(0, len(codedPin), 2)))`

Comment: @jimhark, nah, I don't think it's more helpful then yours :)

Comment: @Zed, part of what made this interesting to me was trying to make it a one-liner. Turns out the best I could as a one-liner is pretty ugly. But it works. You could take it apart. Rewrite it so it returns just 'n' to see what it is. See the individual pieces. Maybe in a couple days I'll come back with a more reasonable version with a 'for' loop. Admittedly '*100**(len(c)/2-i-1)' is a bit of a hack. Good luck.

Comment: @mata, yeah, they're both pretty rough. I'll probably post a proper version in a couple days, multiple lines, real variable names and maybe even comments.

Comment: @jimhark Understood. Thanks for showing me this approach; I'll pick it apart and play with it for a while.

Comment: @Zed, latest version got rid of n and the '*100**(len(c)/2-i-1)' hack.